# Regex validation on Account Address field

Tags: regex, validation, salesforce

We sync our Salesforce accounts and opportunities to QuickBooks (QB), but QB has character limits on its fields. Street lines have a 41 character limit per line and I'm trying to have regex control and limit this, but it isn't working on the Address field type. I am using the very simple conditional formula:

```
REGEX(BillingStreet, '.{42,}')
```

which matches any non-linebreak character and if it's 42 characters or more, trigger the validation. The problem is that it ignores this rule. I know this formula works because if I apply it to another text field, it works how it's supposed to. Here's an example of how it should work: https://www.regexpal.com/99217. If there's a match anywhere, it should throw the validation error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with `^$` anchors?

Comment: Is a carriage return or line feed sneaking into BillingStreet and making the regex fail? . doesn't match \n

Comment: I want it to be per line like in the example link. The example is correct, but putting the same text in the field does not trigger the validation. The field in Salesforce is a text area, but when it syncs to QuickBooks, it separates each line and puts them into one of the 5 address block lines where each line has a 41 character limit. I'll try the ^$ anchor though.

Comment: @ctwheels I did ```^.{42,}$``` and it only works if there is one line. I need to support multiline.

Comment: Add the `m` modifier to make it multiline

Comment: I am a noob with regex. Where would I put that? I tried ```/^.{42,}$/m``` and now just one line doesn't cause it to error anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using Regex because it doesn't seem to work well. Instead I used formulas to make sure it follows the validation. Since we have a limit of two lines, it wasn't too bad to do this the long way.

```
AND(
 IF( 
  //Look for a line break. If there is one, split and compare lengths separately.
  FIND(MID( $Setup.Global__c.CLRF__c ,3,1), BillingStreet ) > 0
 ,
  IF(
   //If the first line is over the limit, return true to trigger validation.
   LEN(LEFT(BillingStreet, FIND(MID( $Setup.Global__c.CLRF__c ,3,1), BillingStreet )-2))>41
  ,
   TRUE
  ,
   //If first line is fine, check second line and since this is a condition, it will return true/false automatically.
   LEN(MID(BillingStreet, FIND(MID( $Setup.Global__c.CLRF__c ,3,1), BillingStreet )+1,LEN(BillingStreet))) > 41
  )
 ,
  //If there is no line break (one line) check the total length.
  LEN(BillingStreet) > 41
 )
,
 //There is a validation for having more than 2 lines. Without this, it will combine lines 2 and above and check that length and will be confusing to users when it's > 41.
 NOT(REGEX( BillingStreet , '(.*\r?\n.*){2,}'))
,
 //Ignore this rule if the user has this flag active. Useful for bulk updating and don't have to worry about import errors.
 $User.Bypass_Validation__c = False 
)
```

This piece `MID( $Setup.Global__c.CLRF__c ,3,1)` represents a line break in Salesforce. Found out how it works from [find line break in formula field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18909/find-line-break-in-formula-field). I would have liked to use Regex, but it just doesn't work if you ask me. Except for checking 2+ lines like in the above code.